# I want sum_char2cust and sum_cust2char only for top 20 document of user

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

```
GET chatsession/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "char2cust": {
              "gte": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_name",
        "size": 99999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_char2cust": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "char2cust"
          }
        },
        "sum_cust2char": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cust2char"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I want sum_char2cust and sum_cust2char only for top 20 document of
> unique user. I have tried using top_hits and other solutions but not
> worked for me.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, you want to calculate the sum agg on **top 20 documents**. But on what basis/field value are your top documents determined ? Is it on the basis of the `user_name` field ? It would be better if you could share a sample document along with your expected search results.

Comment: @ESCoder I want `desc` of `id`

Comment: It is auto incremented value in documents.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should gives you expected result

```
GET chatsession/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "char2cust": {
              "gte": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_name",
        "size": 20         --> Note here.
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_char2cust": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "char2cust"
          }
        },
        "sum_cust2char": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cust2char"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amit for response but this return 20 results but I want sum_char2cust and sum_cust2char only for top 20 document of unique user.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the sum of `char2cust` and `cust2char` field, for top 20 users (based on their id), you need to [sort the terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) result based on the [Max Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) result.

Try out this below query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "char2cust": {
                            "gte": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "uniq_user": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_name",
                "size": 20,
                "order": {
                    "latestOrder": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sum_char2cust": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "char2cust"
                    }
                },
                "sum_cust2char": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "cust2char"
                    }
                },
                "latestOrder": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want sum of `char2cust` and `cust2char` only for latest 20 documents of a user not for top 20 users. I want to apply `Sum` aggregation on latest 20 documents for a particular user.

Comment: please check response below

Comment: @SouravSinghGehlot so the issue is with the doc_count, rest of the other values are correct in the response ? Lets continue this discussion here (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244959/es)

Comment: can you please share query here??